# Create form with two action and one button submit

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

In the form I want call one of two Servlet if an event occurred..
Why does it not works?

```
<form method="post" action="<%=tipo_ricerca.equals('normale') ? VisualizzaRecensioniServlet : VisualizzaRecensioniRicercaVotoServlet;%>">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="parentNode.submit()">Start</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Please give some more details. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I have a error :Illegal start of expression,unclosed caracter litteral,not a statement

Comment: Try "VisualizzaRecensioniServlet" : "VisualizzaRecensioniRicercaVotoServlet" , you are trying to set dinamically the servlet to which you will make the POST call depending on the equals result

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix javascript and Java in a way that makes no sense.

First of all, you don't even have a submit button; you have a regular link that is not even formatted correctly.  Replace

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="parentNode.submit()">Start</a>
```

with

```
<input type='submit' value='Start' />
```

Or, since you don't have any values in your form, you don't really need a form, and thus could just use a link like this:

```
<a href="<%=tipo_ricerca.equals('normale') ? VisualizzaRecensioniServlet : VisualizzaRecensioniRicercaVotoServlet;%>">Start</a>
```

Secondly, if you want to call another servlet from Java, use `response.sendRedirect()` or something of that nature.  If you want to call the servlet from Javascript, `<%=somevar%>` is not of any use for that since the server-side processing is over before Javascript begins running on the client.  Unless your intent was to set which servlet to use while the server-side code was being processed.

Comment: I use javascript because I want to create a form without a button..I send some parameters to  the servlet